# Oracle exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I run a normal sql query on oracle table:

```
select name from table;
```

I get the desired result.

When however I run it as pl/sql, I keep getting the error `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`:

```
declare
l_name VARCHAR(200);

begin
select name into l_name from table;
end;
```

I understand that the error is telling me I am trying to insert more rows into `l_name` but how do I make `l_name` dynamic as the search will *almost* always return more than 1 result.

The reason pl/sql is used is because I need to show a list of items based on a search as `http` on Oracle Apex and normal sql code cannot do this.

```
htp.p('Names found: '||TO_CHAR(l_name));
```

Comment: Hints: 1) make l_name an table type of varchar2; 2) make a procedure, where it lists your result;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop. Here is a (very rough) example that lets you iterate over all matching rows, and prints each name with a semicolon terminator.

```
htp.prn('Names found: ');    
for my_data in (select name from table) loop
    htp.prn(to_char(my_data.name) || '; ');
end loop;
htp.p(''); -- newline
```

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer and not Hints :) Appreciated.

Comment: one question, is it at all possible to use newline as separator instead of semicolon?

Comment: @Jacob just use `htp.p` in the loop body and remove it from the end. The difference between `htp.prn` and `htp.p` is precisely that `htp.p` adds a newline while `htp.prn` just prints its parameter as-is.